# How to use TextRenderer.DrawText to get ellipsis at the start

Tags: .net, winforms

The [TextRenderer.DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160657.aspx) method has a [TextFormatFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags.aspx) parameter. Using `TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis` allows you to abbreviate the text with an ellipsis at the end so that it fits in the available space. However, I want to put the ellipsis at the start. Curiously enough there is no `TextFormatFlags` value to do this.

I've considered progressively shortening the string myself until it fits according to [TextRenderer.MeasureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx), but I'm worried about performance. Surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than shortening, you should lengthen in "binary-search" fashion.

Since a string could be considerably longer than the visible area, if you start with one character, and grow by a factor of 2 each iteration, then shrink by a few characters at a time once you're beyond your length limit, you should have a performant truncation algorithm.

Comment: This is what I have implemented now, except that I use a full dichotomic search (instead of "shrinking by a few characters at a time"). Good tip on the lengthening, I hadn't considered the "huge string" case.